# Está correto o cálculo do RENAVAN? Tem como melhorar algo?

Tags: c#, lógica

Olá, eu estou pesquisando na internet e encontrei [nesse site](https://ivanmeirelles.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/validar-renavam-em-c/) um código em C# de como calcular o RENAVAM, eu mexi um pouco, mas eu não consigo encontrar em nenhum lugar que explique como realmente funciona o calculo do RENAVAM então eu não sei se essa lógica está correta.

[Código no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hgb65B#&togetherjs=w3FsJtSosV)

Código:

```
public static bool isRENAVAM(string RENAVAM)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RENAVAM.Trim()))
                return false;

            int[] d = new int[11];
            //sequencia para calcular o RENAVAM
            string sequencia = "3298765432";
            string SoNumero = Regex.Replace(RENAVAM, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SoNumero))
                return false;

            //verificando se todos os numeros são iguais 
            if (new string(SoNumero[0], SoNumero.Length) == SoNumero) 
                return false;

            SoNumero = Convert.ToInt64(SoNumero).ToString("00000000000");

            int v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            d[i] = Convert.ToInt32(SoNumero.Substring(i, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            v += d[i] * Convert.ToInt32(sequencia.Substring(i, 1));

        v = (v * 10) % 11;
        v = (v != 10) ? v : 0;

        return (v == d[10]);
    }
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

**1.** Este código para calcular o RENAVAM está correto?

**2.** Qual é a lógica para calcular o RENAVAM?

**3.** Tem algo que eu posso melhorar nesse código?

Comment: 1 - Testa aqui com esses numeros http://gerador.info/renavam                         2 - Boa pergunta                                                                                             3 - Sim, só de bater o olho tem umas 2 coisas que eu mudaria

Comment: @PauloHDSousa poderia postar o código com as mudanças que tu faria e com a explicação do pq tu mudaria elas? (Obs. sim sou novo nesse mundo da programação '-')

Comment: eu testei varias vezes e deu certo, e testei com numeros quebrados e deu as respostas certas, acho que vou usar esse código mesmo, com as suas melhorias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma melhoria no código:

```
    public static bool IsRENAVAM(string RENAVAM)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RENAVAM.Trim()))
            return false;

        var sequencia = new int[]{ 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        var soNumero = Regex.Replace(RENAVAM, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(soNumero))
            return false;
        //verificando se todos os numeros são iguais 
        if (soNumero.Distinct().Count() ==1 )
            return false;

        var d = soNumero.ToCharArray().Select(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())).Take(11);
        var v = (d.Zip(sequencia, (n, seq) => n * seq).Sum() * 10) % 11;            
        v = (v != 10) ? v : 0;
        return (v == d.ElementAt(10));
    }
}
```

Utilizando o `Zip` de `Enumerable` mata um loop o que diminui complexidade ciclomática e quantidade de linhas, convertendo o a string `soNumero` para um `IEnumerable<int>` é muito mais performático que converter para long e para string novamente, [link para entender um pouco melhor porque usei Zip em um enumerador ao invés de foreach em um array](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/01/internals-of-loops-while-for-and.html)

Comment: Poderia explicar porque esta maneira é melhor?

Comment: Eu também, realmente, queria saber porque ela é melhor.

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido falar de um método .Zip, obrigado. +1

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código um pouco melhorado

```
public static bool isRENAVAM(string RENAVAM)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RENAVAM.Trim()))
                return false;

            string SoNumero = Regex.Replace(RENAVAM, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SoNumero) || new string(SoNumero[0], SoNumero.Length) == SoNumero)
                return false;

            int[] d = new int[11];
            string sequencia = "3298765432";

            SoNumero = Convert.ToInt64(SoNumero).ToString("00000000000");

            int v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            d[i] = Convert.ToInt32(SoNumero.Substring(i, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            v += d[i] * Convert.ToInt32(sequencia.Substring(i, 1));

        v = (v * 10) % 11;
        v = (v != 10) ? v : 0;

        return (v == d[10]);
    }
```

Comment: ah sim, juntar as verificações e declarar o que nao vai ser usado agora depois, obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Poderia explicar porque esta maneira é melhor?

Comment: Não é tão melhor assim, só coloquei DEPOIS do return as variáveis que vão ser usadas apenas se tiver correto os números e coloquei as 2 verificações em 1... ta mais para uma limpeza que maneira melhor.